# Consistency result vs. True in every model of Axiom X

Tags: logic, set-theory

Suppose a forcing extension of ZFC has been found which satisfies statement $A$. For example, say the extension is formed by Cohen or Laver forcing, so that the model satisfies $\neg$CH.  At this point, would there be any value in showing $\neg$CH implies $A$ (i.e., $A$ holds in *every* model of ZFC+$\neg$CH)? If so, please share any cases (hypothetical/actual) where there would be/has been added value. Thanks!

Comment: The only "added value" in such models seems to be that not just A but also (A and not-CH) is consistent.

Comment: (-1) for it is unclear what your question is.

Comment: I guess "value" is subjective, but I am asking why a direct proof from a given independent axiom should be pursued in favor of any old consistency result.

Comment: I guess I didn't understand the question but surely showing not-CH implies A has "more value" than simply showing the consistency of A. Another example would be: It is better to show V=L implies CH than to show that CH can be forced. At least Jensen would agree.

Comment: $A$ may be interesting/useful on its own. Knowing that $A$ holds whenever CH fails obviously helps more than having to prove $A$ in each model of interest, perhaps by *ad hoc* methods.

Comment: Good question. Is there anything special about $\neg$CH? For instance, For instance, if you have a forcing proof that a statement A is consistent with ZF+AC, is there any added value in proving that ZF+AC implies A?

Answer (score 3):

First of all, forcing extensions are of **models** of $\sf ZFC$. The difference is that $\sf ZFC$ is syntactic, it's a theory in a language, forcing is (usually) treated as a semantic construct which allows us to generate a new model of set theory from a previous one.

To your question, if we would have known that **every** model where $\sf CH$ fails is a model obtained by forcing (Cohen, Laver, or otherwise), then this might have been enough - to show that every forcing which forces the violation of $\sf CH$ implies $A$ - to prove that $\lnot\sf CH$ implies $A$.

Alas, we don't know that. We don't know that every model where the continuum hypothesis fails, is in fact a non-trivial forcing extension.

For example, suppose that $V$ is a universe of $\sf ZFC$ if $\varphi(x)$ defines an inner model of $V$, then we can write a formula $\psi(r)$ which states that $r$ is a Cohen generic set over the model defined by $\varphi$. Therefore in any model where Cohen reals are used to violate $\sf CH$ the statement $\exists y(y\text{ is uncountable, and }\forall x\in y(x\text{ is Cohen over }\varphi(x))$
(Note that ground models are definable so there is $\varphi$ which defines the ground model, if we force over it.)

In general, forcing is used to prove the consistency of statements. It can be used to prove statements outright. For example, if you can use forcing to prove that Goldbach's conjecture is true, then you have in fact proved it because of Shoenfield's absoluteness theorem, stating that simple-enough number theoretical statements are absolute between two models with the same ordinals (such as a model of $\sf ZFC$ and any of its forcing extensions).

Comment: Interesting that in some cases these may be equivalent, but my guess is that these cases are rare. If you were faced with a situation like the one I described, would you attempt a direct proof?

Comment: What do you mean by "these cases"? And I can't really say because I don't know what $A$ is.